# force onLayout in a subView whose dimensions doesn't change

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup

I have a Custom `ViewGroup` with some views inside.

In response to an event, a requestLayout is called and in `OnLayout` some of the views will 
get a new layout position.

One of them maintain its position but needs to be rearranged inside. However this view's onlayout method will not be called since its layout position doesn't change. Trying to call `requestLayout`, `forceLayout` or `invalidate` in this view doesn't work.

The only dirty trick that I have found is to change some of its value position to force the layout change, but I think there should be a better way. So, by now I do something (horrible) like:

```
    int patch = 0;
    @Override protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        ...
        _myView.patchedLayout(patch);
        _myview.layout(l1, t1 , r1, t1+patch);
        patch = (patch+1) % 2;
        ...
    }
```

Any way to get the same result in a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got the solution: I need to override `onMeasure` and be sure to call `mesure` in my view:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    ...
    _myview.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    ...
```

It will set the LAYOUT_REQUIRED flag in the view's private field mPrivateFlags so it will force to call `onLayout`